# Magento2 : Add Store view field in admin

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml

In my site having two stores.I want to show store views select option in custom module in  adminhtml.How to add functionality for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add field with this code

```
<field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enabeld </label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
```

for get the value

```
const TEST_TEST_ENABLED  = 'test/test/enabled';
protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
   ....
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
) {



.....
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
   ....
}
public function getEnabled()
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        self::TEST_TEST_ENABLED,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

Comment: Whenever i select default config to other store view the module disable,for appear how to add in system.xml

Comment: @Nadh you want to add module disabled in system configuration?

Comment: i want to select option for particular store

Comment: you have to change `store view` of in configuration  and values will be store for **current store view** you don't to add store view with that. you can get values `\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE` for current scope.